# Is the answer true? $\sup \frac{(\theta-\theta')^2}{\exp(n(\theta'-\theta))-1}=\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: inequality, self-learning

I am trying to calculate the supremum ($sup$) for some equation, Is the answer true?

$$\sup \frac{(\theta-\theta')^2}{\exp(n(\theta'-\theta))-1}=\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Comment: Over what set are you taking the supremum?

Comment: for $var_{\theta}(T(x))\geq sup \frac{(\theta-\theta')^2}{exp(n(\theta'-\theta))-1}=\frac{1}{n^2}$ with $\theta' \geq \theta$

Comment: If its only with respect to one variable, use single variable calc and follow a similar procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the change of variables $u=n(\theta'-\theta)$, this is
$$
\sup_u\frac{u^2/n^2}{\exp(u)-1}=\frac1{n^2}\cdot\sup_u\frac{u^2}{\exp(u)-1}.
$$
The last ratio is negative when $u\lt0$ hence one should study it on $(0,+\infty)$. Upon inspection, it is maximum around $u=1.5936$ where its value is about $0.6476$.

Thus, the answer to the question in the title is: No.

Comment: yes, it works in my computational..merci @did for your best input..

Comment: You are welcome. What did you try to solve this before asking? And why did you delete several recent questions of yours?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your taking the supremum over $\theta, \theta^{\prime}$. I would use techniques from calculus to find a maximum value. One approach is to define sequence of multivariable functions
$$F_{n}(\theta, \theta^{\prime})=\frac{(\theta-\theta^{\prime})^{2}}{e^{n(\theta^{\prime}-\theta)}-1}$$
Now for each $n$ calculate the gradient, find the critical points, text for local maximum. You should also check the behavior as the magnitude of $\vert(\theta, \theta^{\prime})\vert$ gets large. For this, I would switch to polar coordinates and take a limit as $r\to \infty$. If you get something unbounded, the supremum must be $\pm \infty$. If bounded, compare with the values of $F_{n}$ at critical points and see which is the largest.

Comment: Since $F_{n}$ is not defined on the line $\theta=\theta^{\prime}$, you should check those limits too.